# How to set Html Content in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am working on eCommerce Project where Html text editor is needed and i choose TinyMCE. TinyMCE is nice editor for editing text.

I use Asp.net MVC4 and mysql database for storing data of tinyMCE.
I am easily able to get the content of tinyMCE editor By using

```
tinymce.get("textfull").getContent({ format: 'raw' }).replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

this code provide me HTML encoded text but i want to show this text on new tinyMCE Editor by using this code

```
tinymce.get("textfull").setContent($("<div/>").html(d.Description).text());
```

but this code set html Text not Html rendered content on browser
[image: TinyMCE Result]

Please tell me what is the correct way to show as HTML Element not text.

Comment: Did you try to refresh the tinyMCE after data is set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
tinymce.get("textfull").getBody().innerHTML = $("").html(d.Description).text();
```

or

```
tinymce.get("textfull").getBody().innerHTML = d.Description;
```